# ActionLink/RouteLink based on URL not Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller that uses the following structure:

```
.com/Object/375
```

However, I can also use the following URL when I am accessing special admin rights

```
.com/Admin/Object/375
```

I use the same user controls whether you're in the Admin section or not, but they both point to the same Controller *Object*. I need for the links to maintain that URL structure and not try to kick an Admin user back to the Object controller. I am currently using the route name method, where these are my route names (in global.asax):

```
"Admin/-Object"
"Object/-Object"
"Object-Object"
```

These route names catch the following routes:

```
Admin/Object, Admin/Object/555, Object, Object/323
```

I then use the following in a route link

```
Html.RouteLink(id, Request.Url.Segments[1] + "-Object", new { id = id })
```

This works just fine, but has an odd smell - any other ideas?

To clarify: I need the URL to be properly created based on the current URL structure (with or without the Admin) and the routing will point to the correct controller (the same for both URLs) and the admin specific content will be injected into the page only if in the Admin section (based on URL).

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the links to point to the same controller regardless of user role/permissions, but to different action methods?

Comment: They are pointing to the same controller (routing handles this), I just need for the correct URL to be created based on the current URL structure. So that if they are in the Admin section, they continue to stay in the Admin section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap this up, using ViewBag is probably a better idea because using the URL segment might result in unexpected errors, especialy if you move the controls or views around.